# contour interval with kernel density estimation method in matlab

Tags: matlab, kernel, contour

I'd like to know how to make [contour line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line#Temperature_and_related_subjects) values ​​of a matrix which contains latitude, longitude and temperature for several temperature sensors using kernel density estimation method.

Details:

A set of sensors captures temperature readings over a geographical area, so I have a temperature log with one temperature value every 5 seconds.

The data looks like this:

```
sensor_ID latitude longitude time   temperature 
010001    27.8831  -0.2831   0:0:0  9.0 
010001    27.8831  -0.2831   0:0:5  9.0
010001    27.8831  -0.2831   0:0:10 9.0
010001    27.8831  -0.2831   0:0:15 9.1
010001    27.8831  -0.2831   0:0:20 9.1
010001    27.8831  -0.2831   0:0:25 9.1
010001    27.8831  -0.2831   0:0:30 9.1
010001    27.8831  -0.2831   0:0:35 9.0
010001    27.8831  -0.2831   0:0:40 9.1
010001    27.8831  -0.2831   0:0:50 9.0
010001    27.8831  -0.2831   0:0:55 9.0
010001    27.8831  -0.2831   0:1:0  9.0
010001    27.8831  -0.2831   0:1:5  9.0
010001    27.8831  -0.2831   0:1:10 9.0
```

For 48 sensors i have total of 812,163 lines so I have a matrix of size `812163 x 5`.
It now seeks to draw the [contour line(isotherm)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line#Temperature_and_related_subjects) values ​​for each temperature that is to say to interpolate with KDE.
For the moment I do not take time into account

Comment: Is your question *how to implement the kernel density estimation method* or do you want to know *how to use an existing implementation in matlab*?

Comment: Hello scenia
I has a dot matrix uniformly distributed over a surface.
For each point I have coordinates (longitude, latitude and temperature)
Looking depending on coordinates of temperature create polygon contours.
Do you know the approach already exists in Matlab?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with contours or the kernel density estimation method, so I can't really help you. I can only try to help you clarify your question so someone who does know how to do this understands what you want. What is the dimension/size of your matrix?

Comment: ok I'll explain again:

Comment: Much, much better. I'll edit your post a little to fix the grammar and link to the English article. Hopefully, this will help find someone who can help you.

Comment: thank you very much scenia but I surment edit at the same time and you but I failed thank you for your understanding

Comment: Ok, now an expert will be able to understand it and help you :)

Comment: I found the function kde2d performed by Zdravko Botev kde2d (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17204-kernel-density-estimation/content/kde2d.m) but i don't know how to apply to my datasets :
function [bandwidth, density, X, Y] = kde2d (data, n, MIN_XY, MAX_XY)
 
Here a data is in matrixs 2dimensions, or I have:
X, Y, Z = lat, lon, temperature
does anyone has an idea about it
thank you

Comment: Where does the `812163` come from? If you take one temperature every 5 seconds, you should have `17281` data points per sensor, so `829488` total.

Comment: thank you scenia for the remark is true i had forgotten  1 sensor because it's me who create the temperature simulator.
thank you again :)